# Find element in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I select from the following HTML the `<div class="corner dirty">` when I click on the `<a class="btn btn-primary active"...</a>` button ?

```
<div class="profile-header col-sm-4 ">
    <div class="corner dirty">
        <span>Sale</span>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-cover">
        <h1>01</h1>
        <p>-</p>
    </div>
    <div class="promo-footer-white">
        <div class="row no-gutter">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="text-center">

                    <div class="input-group text-center">
                        <div class="switchStatus btn-group" data-id="35" data-module="housekeeping_rooms_status_edit" data-reload="no">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary active" data-status="clean">Propre</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary inactive" data-status="dirty">Sale</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I tried:

```
$(this).closest('.corner');
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `parents` and `find`

Like

```
$(this).parents('.profile-header').find(".corner")
```

Snippet:

```js
$(function() {
 $(".switchStatus a").click(function(){
  console.log( $(this).parents('.profile-header').find(".corner").text() );
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="profile-header col-sm-4 ">
  <div class="corner dirty">
    <span>Sale</span>
  </div>
  <div class="profile-cover">
    <h1>01</h1>
    <p>-</p>
  </div>
  <div class="promo-footer-white">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="text-center">

          <div class="input-group text-center">
            <div class="switchStatus btn-group" data-id="35" data-module="housekeeping_rooms_status_edit" data-reload="no">
              <a class="btn btn-primary active" data-status="clean">Propre</a>
              <a class="btn btn-primary inactive" data-status="dirty">Sale</a>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello. What about if I start with `$(".switchStatus a").click(function(){` please? Thanks.

Comment: Can you `console.log(this)`? And check what is logging?

Answer (score 0):

$(this).closest('.profile-header').find('.corner');

Should do the trick for you.

Comment: Why my solution doesn't work please ? And btw, it doesn't work with your proposition...

Answer (score 0):

This will do...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(document).on('click','.btn.btn-primary.active',function () {
               alert($('.corner.dirty').html());
            });
        });
</script>
```